# Why does my TensorFlow Convnet (attempted) training result in NaN gradients?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have modified the MNIST (28x28) Convnet tutorial code to accept larger images (150x150). But when I try to train I receive this error (see end for full stack trace):

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1076] 0x2e97d30 Compute status: Invalid argument: ReluGrad input is not finite. : Tensor had NaN values
```

Here's my code. Worryingly, I get the same error when using image data from disk as when generating noisy red/blue/green squares and trying to classify them by colour. The code that generates RGB data is different to the code that scans directories for JPG image data. So either there is some systematically wrong way I am loading in my own data, or there is something wrong with my proposed architecture. (I could include these modules but I worry it might make this post unreadably long.)

EDIT: I have tried this same code with moderately larger images (30x30) and it DOES work. So perhaps the error is related to the very high dimensionality of a (150x150) problem?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import data.image_loader

###############################
##### Set hyperparameters #####
###############################

num_epochs = 2
width = 150
height = 150
num_categories = 2
num_channels = 3
batch_size = 100 # for my sanity
num_training_examples = 2000
num_test_examples = 200

num_batches = num_training_examples/batch_size

####################################################################################
##### It's convenient to define some methods to perform frequent routine tasks #####
####################################################################################

def weight_variable(shape):
    '''
    Generates a TensorFlow Tensor. This Tensor gets initialized with values sampled from the truncated normal
    distribution. Its purpose will be to store model parameters.
    :param shape: The dimensions of the desired Tensor
    :return: The initialized Tensor
    '''
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    '''
    Generates a TensorFlow Tensor. This Tensor gets initialized with values sampled from <some?> distribution.
    Its purpose will be to store bias values.
    :param shape: The dimensions of the desired Tensor
    :return: The initialized Tensor
    '''
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
    '''
    Generates a conv2d TensorFlow Op. This Op flattens the weight matrix (filter) down to 2D, then "strides" across the
    input Tensor x, selecting windows/patches. For each little_patch, the Op performs a right multiply:
            W . little_patch
    and stores the result in the output layer of feature maps.
    :param x: a minibatch of images with dimensions [batch_size, height, width, 3]
    :param W: a "filter" with dimensions [window_height, window_width, input_channels, output_channels]
    e.g. for the first conv layer:
          input_channels = 3 (RGB)
          output_channels = number_of_desired_feature_maps
    :return: A TensorFlow Op that convolves the input x with the filter W.
    '''
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    '''
    Genarates a max-pool TensorFlow Op. This Op "strides" a window across the input x. In each window, the maximum value
    is selected and chosen to represent that region in the output Tensor. Hence the size/dimensionality of the problem
    is reduced.
    :param x: A Tensor with dimensions [batch_size, height, width, 3]
    :return: A TensorFlow Op that max-pools the input Tensor, x.
    '''
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                          strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


############################
##### Set up the model #####
############################

x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, height, width, num_channels])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, width, height, num_channels])
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, num_categories])

#1st conv layer
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, num_channels, 32]) #5x5 conv window, 3 colour channels, 32 outputted feature maps
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

#2nd conv layer
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

#fully connected layer
W_fc1 = weight_variable([38 * 38 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 38*38*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

#droupout
keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

#softmax output layer
W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, num_categories])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([num_categories])
y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

#saving model
saver = tf.train.Saver()

###################################
##### Load data from the disk #####
###################################

dataset = data.image_loader.ImageLoad(base_path="/home/hal9000/Datasets/id_dataset3",
                                      num_categories=num_categories,
                                      width=width,
                                      height=height)

data_training = np.asarray(np.split(dataset.data_training, num_batches))
labels_training = np.asarray(np.split(dataset.labels_training, num_batches))

data_test = np.split(dataset.data_test, 1)
labels_test = np.split(dataset.labels_test, 1)

####################################################
##### Train the model and evaluate performance #####
####################################################

with tf.Session() as sess:
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y_conv))
    #train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0005).minimize(cross_entropy)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    for j in range(num_epochs):
        for i in range(num_batches):
            train_step.run(feed_dict={x: np.asarray(data_training[i]), y_: np.asarray(labels_training[i]), keep_prob: 0.5})

        print "=== EPOCH: " + str(j) + " ==="
        print "test accuracy: %g \n"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: data_test[i], y_: labels_test[i], keep_prob: 1.0})

    saver.save(sess, "saved_models/convnet_image" + str(j) + ".ckpt")
```

Error:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc:40] Local device intra op parallelism threads: 8
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:58] Direct session inter op parallelism threads: 8
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1076] 0xc8991e0 Compute status: Invalid argument: ReluGrad input is not finite. : Tensor had NaN values
     [[Node: gradients/Relu_grad/Relu/CheckNumerics = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="ReluGrad input is not finite.", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](add)]]
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1076] 0xc8991e0 Compute status: Invalid argument: ReluGrad input is not finite. : Tensor had NaN values
     [[Node: gradients/Relu_1_grad/Relu_1/CheckNumerics = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="ReluGrad input is not finite.", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](add_1)]]
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1076] 0xc8991e0 Compute status: Invalid argument: ReluGrad input is not finite. : Tensor had NaN values
     [[Node: gradients/Relu_2_grad/Relu_2/CheckNumerics = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="ReluGrad input is not finite.", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](add_2)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hal9000/PycharmProjects/TensorFlow_Experiments_0.4/neural_nets/image_convnet.py", line 137, in <module>
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: np.asarray(data_training[i]), y_: np.asarray(labels_training[i]), keep_prob: 0.5})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1325, in run
    _run_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2945, in _run_using_default_session
    session.run(operation, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 368, in run
    results = self._do_run(target_list, unique_fetch_targets, feed_dict_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 444, in _do_run
    e.code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: ReluGrad input is not finite. : Tensor had NaN values
     [[Node: gradients/Relu_grad/Relu/CheckNumerics = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="ReluGrad input is not finite.", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](add)]]
Caused by op u'gradients/Relu_grad/Relu/CheckNumerics', defined at:
  File "/home/hal9000/PycharmProjects/TensorFlow_Experiments_0.4/neural_nets/image_convnet.py", line 131, in <module>
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0005).minimize(cross_entropy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 186, in minimize
    aggregation_method=aggregation_method)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 232, in compute_gradients
    aggregation_method=aggregation_method)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py", line 445, in gradients
    in_grads = _AsList(grad_fn(op_wrapper, *out_grads))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_grad.py", line 126, in _ReluGrad
    t = _VerifyTensor(op.inputs[0], op.name, "ReluGrad input is not finite.")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_grad.py", line 119, in _VerifyTensor
    verify_input = array_ops.check_numerics(t, message=msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 48, in check_numerics
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 664, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1834, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1043, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

...which was originally created as op u'Relu', defined at:
  File "/home/hal9000/PycharmProjects/TensorFlow_Experiments_0.4/neural_nets/image_convnet.py", line 82, in <module>
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 547, in relu
    return _op_def_lib.apply_op("Relu", features=features, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 664, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1834, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1043, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One likely source of trouble is the `tf.log(y_conv)`, which will emit NaN values for any zeroes in `y_conv`. The [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) operator offers a numerically stable (and more efficient) version of your loss calculation. The following should work better:

```
logits = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, y_)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting NaN values, it is probably because your learning rate is high relative to your loss function. I would suggest you to try lower learning rates like `1e-5` or `1e-6`. This used to solve problem in my case.

Comment: Hi, I find your answer seems works for me. Here is my question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47247675/difference-between-distribute-and-local-machine-version-when-training-by-tensorf

Comment: But I am confused why it happens, could you plz offer some tips or understandings if there is ? Thanks a lot.